# Clone and Push using libgit2sharp

Tags: c#, github, github-api, libgit2, libgit2sharp

Can anyone tell me how to Clone a repo and Push or publish the committed changes?

Currently i am able to modify the clone repo and able to commit my changes, but i dont fine an api to push it. also to clone the repo initially.

if its not available,What is the alternative to do in using c#?

-Jaffer

Answer (score 5):

> Can anyone tell me how to Clone a repo and Push or publish the committed changes?
>   Currently i am able to modify the clone repo and able to commit my changes, but i dont fine an api to push it. also to clone the repo initially.

`Clone` and `Push` features are currently under development in libgit2. Below some PRs related to this subject.

- **Clone:**  [Issue #778](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/pull/778)
- **Push:**  [Issue # 761](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/pull/761) and [Issue #803](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/pull/803). Some additional PRs will be required to fulfill the whole functionality

Once the C code is reviewed, merged and tested, a new version of LibGit2Sharp will be released exposing those features.

Considering the current progress, `Clone` might land before `Push` and thus usable from LibGit2Sharp sooner.

> if its not available,What is the alternative to do in using c#?

You could defer this to `git.exe` by invoking it through the **[Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx)** type. This would require to deploy **[msysgit](http://msysgit.github.com/)** on the computer running the .Net code, though.

### Update

Both `Clone` and `Push` are now available in LibGit2Sharp.

- This **[test](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/blob/vNext/LibGit2Sharp.Tests/CloneFixture.cs#L53-L90)** shows how do to a Clone and a Push over against a local repository
- Other hints regarding handling of credentials and callbacks can be seen in the **[Remote](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/blob/vNext/LibGit2Sharp.Tests/RemoteFixture.cs)** and **[Clone](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/blob/vNext/LibGit2Sharp.Tests/CloneFixture.cs)** test suites.

Answer (score 0):

Clone is implemented now. I hope push is around the corner -- the C version looks to be implemented, but haven't been merged yet.